# add sub collection firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I add a subcollection to a firestore document at the time I create the document? Let's see if I explain what I'm trying to do is create a sub-collection (in this case, images) at the same time the document is generated. So far I have achieved it but separately. How can I do so that when this document is generated, this reference will also be generated?

[image]

This code works for me but for an already created document:

```
this.afs.doc ('projects / 2ZFyHTTQhvIqnLHVgQeK'). Collection ('imagenes'). Add (image);
```

Can someone help me to better focus on the subject?

I made a stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfwhjn?embed=1&file=app/services/firebase.service.ts

Comment: Have you tried using a batch write?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: From what I read in the documentation, this is more focused on updating large amounts of data. On the contrary, what I want is to create a document that contains a sub collection.

Comment: So, have you tried a batch write for that?  It sounds like you want to write two documents at the exact same time, and a batch write will do that.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to see it in detail. Although I told you that I only want to generate a document and it seems to me that this batch writing is for already created documents. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can definite create new documents with a batch write using the `set` operation.